# Bad Access C++ Error

Tags: c++, xcode7, exc-bad-access

Can you help me fix a bad access error please?
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int t,tr=0;
    cin>>t;

while (tr<t) {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int distance=n;
    int number;
    number=n*n;
    int spiral[n][n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            spiral[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n;) {
        for (int j=0; j<n;) {
            spiral[i][j]=number;
            number=number-1;
            //cout<<"ij"<<endl;
            for (int k=0; k<distance; k++) {
                i++;
               spiral[i][j]=number;
                number--;
                //cout<<"k"<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            cout<<spiral[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    tr++;
}

return 0;
}
```

Bad  access is on

```
spiral[i][j]=number;
```

Here is the link for the problem but this is not important at the moment. I tried nszmobies but it didn't work so I'm asking you.
This is c++.
[Here is the problem](https://www.hackerearth.com/june-circuits/algorithm/leaf-and-limelight-attack-circuit/#c58723).

Comment: Run your program in the debugger and check the values of `i` and `j` at that line.

Comment: On the line above (the bad access) you have `i++;` here `i` gets incremented for both nested loops and never gets reset (inside the loops) it will eventually get `>=n`.

Comment: Richard Critten's comment (like seleznev anton's answer) explain the particular problem you asked about.   Additionally, `int spiral[n][n];` declares a VLA, which is not valid in C++.   Your compiler, presumably, supports that as an extension.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have errors in your loops. 
Loop

```
for (int j=0; j<n;)
```

looks as it is infinite because j variable isn't changing. Moreover variable i in

```
spiral[i][j]=number;
```

in your program can be greater or equal to n.